# (Internal) fire Simulation with wind force field is too curvy

Tags: smoke-simulation

I have this simple set up that I use every time when simulating Godzilla shooting his atomic breath, and the set up is basically like this. I have a cylinder that's a flow object, the domain, and a wind force field facing the direction of the breath being shot with a strength of 50. Sometimes I notice when I have a set up like this the fire curves too much, what I mean by this is that the flow of it bounces up and down crazily, like a sea or a flag. Is there a way to turn this down in the settings of the domain or flow object or even the forcefield? Thanks!

[image]

Here's a link to the settings for the force field, cylinder, and smoke domain. But you can see it curves a lot which I'm trying to make it not do.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldocz.jpg

Comment: It would be helpful to provide some images of your set up, results, issue, etc. so that others can understand your issue.

Comment: Have you tried reducing Vorticity in the Smoke Flames settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the Vorticity settings to affect the turbulance in the smoke or flame. From the Blender Manual pages :

> Vorticity
>   Controls the amount of turbulence in the smoke. Higher values will make lots of small swirls, while lower values make smoother shapes.

Reduce Vorticity for a more stable flame.